# Yii 1.1.12 : How to confiure OpCache : I upgraded PHP from 5.3 to 5.5

Tags: php, caching, yii, apc, opcache

I am using Yii 1.1.12 and recently upgraded my PHP from 5.3 to 5.5 and have found that APC is no longer to be used because OpCache has been made part of PHP5.5. In my Yii main.config  file, I have the following entry:

```
'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.caching.CApcCache',
    ),
```

Two questions:

1. I am not able to find what should I change the above entry to so
   that Yii takes it as its cache? I am extensivly using following in my code

Yii::app()->cache->set('some data to be cached', $CACHE_VARIABLES);
$get_var=Yii::app()->cache->get($CACHE_VARIABLES);

2. Am I on the right track or missing
   something else?

Output of PhpInfo shows following Zend Opcache variables (Local and Master values are mentioned in front of each varaible:

**Zend OPcache**

```
Opcode Caching  Up and Running  
Optimization  Enabled  
Startup  OK  
Shared memory model  win32  
Cache hits  731  
Cache misses  144  
Used memory  4487992  
Free memory  62545312  
Wasted memory  75560  
Cached scripts  138  
Cached keys  261  
Max keys  3907  
OOM restarts  0  
Hash keys restarts  0  
Manual restarts  0  

opcache.blacklist_filename no value no value
opcache.consistency_checks 0 0 
    opcache.dups_fix Off Off 
    opcache.enable On On 
    opcache.enable_cli On On 
    opcache.enable_file_override Off Off 
    opcache.error_log no value no value 
    opcache.fast_shutdown 0 0 
    opcache.file_update_protection 2 2 
    opcache.force_restart_timeout 180 180 
    opcache.inherited_hack On On 
    opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4 4 
    opcache.load_comments 0 0 
    opcache.log_verbosity_level 1 1 
    opcache.max_accelerated_files 2000 2000 
    opcache.max_file_size 0 0 
    opcache.max_wasted_percentage 5 5 
    opcache.memory_consumption 64 64 
    opcache.mmap_base no value no value 
    opcache.optimization_level 0xFFFFFFFF 0xFFFFFFFF 
    opcache.preferred_memory_model no value no value 
    opcache.protect_memory 0 0 
    opcache.restrict_api no value no value 
    opcache.revalidate_freq 2 2 
    opcache.revalidate_path Off Off 
    opcache.save_comments 0 0 
    opcache.use_cwd On On 
    opcache.validate_timestamps On On
```

Thanks.

Comment: is opcache loaded in php? run this `<?php phpinfo();` and look for opcache. If it is not present, you will have to enable it in php coniguration. ie `php.ini`

Comment: Yes, I can see a section "Zend OpCache" in Phpinfo() output. This has around 20+ opcache variables .

Comment: What are the value of opcache variables ? may be you want to at this post : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/55295-how-to-use-opcache-in-yii/

Comment: The link you suggested talks about Yii 2.0 whereas I am using Yii 1.1.12. I think, I will have to do some more RnD on which earliest version of Yii supports opcache by default.

Comment: Yii programmatically uses APC user (that is data variable) caching.  OPcache doesn't support this aspect of APC functionality.  You also need to load APCu.  Search the Yii site for APCu and you'll get lots of hits on how to configure this.